# Scala split por llave y coma falla

Tags: json, split, scala, http-get, apache-spark

Como ya indico en el titulo, tengo un problema al hacer un split de un string en scala.

Mi string contiene un JsonList. Por tanto primero borro los corchetes `[ ]` de inicio y de fin, y despues quiero splitear por los simbolos de cerrar llaves y coma `},` (separacion de json en un json list).
Despues concateno de nuevo el simbolo de cerrar llaves `}` para poder serializar el json de string a un case class (con la librerya spray).

```
scala.io.Source.fromURL(endpoint).mkString
          .replace("[", "")
          .replace("]", "")
          .split("},")
          .map(_.concat("}")).toList
          .map(_.parseJson.convertTo[JsonMessageCaseClass])
```

La serializacion a case class funciona perfectamente, llevo usandola ya tiempo.
El error que se muestra es el siguiente (tengo un Try() para capturarlo):

```
ERROR PredictionVars$:71 - Error parsing result:
Expected String as JsString, but got null
```

Se que el error esta en el split porque lo he separado y probaado, y falla justo ahi.

He intentado parsearlo directamente a List[JsonMessageCaseClass] pero parece ser que al framework distribuido con el que trabajo (apache spark) no le gusta porque "no es serializable".

Tampoco uso ninguna librería mas compleja que `scala.io.Source` para realizar la peticion http get y que me de ya implementada la serializacion por los mismos motivos.

Gracias por adelantado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen caracteres para "uso especial" llamados [**metacaracteres**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSSHTQ_7.4.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.4.0/omnibus/wip/common/reference/omn_ref_re_metacharacters.html),

> Los [**metacaracteres**](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSSHTQ_7.4.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.4.0/omnibus/wip/common/reference/omn_ref_re_metacharacters.html) son caracteres no alfabéticos que poseen
> un significado especial en las expresiones regulares. que son :
>
> `\` , `^` , `$` ,  `.` , `|` , `?` , `*` , `+` , `(` , `)` , `{` , `}` , `[`

Si estos son usados directamente para separar una cadena no funcionaran adecuadamente.

Al usar .split() debes usar "\" para escapar estos caracteres, ejemplo:

```
scala.io.Source.fromURL(endpoint).mkString
          .replace("[", "")
          .replace("]", "")
          .split("\\},")
```